# Spinbar / Input Button Visibility

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been working on a spreadsheet that I'm going to use as a template for several more spreadsheets and I've gotten most of the template finished but I would like to add a feature involving the spinbar.

Currently I have 100 input buttons displayed and I know that I will not need 100 buttons for all the possible uses of the template, I just included 100 as a max.

I am looking to add a 1 - 100 spinbar so that it will automatically show/hide buttons depending on the number associated with the spinbar.

I should have no issues figuring out how to hide the buttons or show the buttons, but I cannot figure out the proper code to have buttons visible between 1 - 100.

```
Sub LocNum ()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Worksheets(1).Cell
    For i = 1 To n
```

That's about as far as I can get, so if n is equal to 37 it should only have 37 buttons visible.

I'm getting my code from something I typed up previous before I took a break from it for quite awhile, here is the code.

```
Sub Populate()
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As String
    t = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 1
    i = 0

    For i = 2 To t
        a = i - 1
        If (ActiveSheet.Shapes("" + "btn.index" & i).Visible = True) Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("" + "btn.index" & i).Select
            Selection.OnAction = "" + "Location" & a + ""
            Selection.Characters.Text = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your Buttons has a name standard like "Button 99" in ascending order? You can access Buttons by e.g.  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons(i)` Or like, `Dim oButtons As Object : For Each oButtons In Worksheets("Sheet1").Buttons : Debug.Print oButtons.Caption : Next`

Comment: The button names are btn.index1, btn.index2, etc., I believe I need to have an array of some sort saying

Comment: Sorry for the repost, was trying to find the best way to respond after accidentally hitting enter and it was past 5 minutes to edit.

The button names are btn.index1, btn.index2, etc., I believe I need to have an array of some sort but also an If statement. So if "n" is the spin bar number, anything greater then "n" will set ActiveSheet.Shapes(""+ "btn.index1").Visible = False but right now I'm just drawing a blank on how I would get that going. I know For statements and If statements are required.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure your workflow, but this can help you show/hide the buttons either based on the index (I don't recommend) or the name of the button. You just call this Sub providing the number of buttons to show, rest (index/name higher than the number) will be hidden.

I will let you play with the OnAction.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowButtonsUpTo(ByVal ButtonCount As Long)
    Dim oButton As Button ' or Object

    For Each oButton In Worksheets(1).Buttons
        With oButton
            ' Based on Index (not recommend):
            .Visible = (.Index <= ButtonCount)
            ' Based on Name (button name):
            If InStr(1, .Name, "btn.index", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                .Visible = (CLng(Replace(.Name, "btn.index", "")) <= ButtonCount)
            End If
        End With
    Next oButton

End Sub
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to the code that you provided.